# Entity Framework DbContext instance being disposed when two different instances used as Task

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to run two queries in parallel, which then get loaded into a view.

I'm doing something like this:

```cs
Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> someData;
Task<IEnumerable<MyOtherClass>> someOtherData;

using (MyContext ctx1 = new())
{
    someData = ctx1.MyClass.Where(x => x.ID == id);
}

using (MyContext ctx2 = new())
{
    someOtherData = ctx2.MyOtherClass.Where(x => x.ID == id);
}

await Task.WhenAll(someData, someOtherData);

//Do stuff with someData.Result, someOtherData.Result
```

However, I am getting an `ObjectDisposedException`.

I understand that DbContext is not thread-safe, but this should be creating and using two different instances... So how comes they appear to be using the same one (and thus it is getting disposed before/during the second call)?

The DbContext looks like this:

```cs
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext ()
    {
    }

    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    //Plus OnConfiguring, OnModelCreating, etc
}
```

Comment: So, you have disposed contexts and executed queries. Nice. Put `Task.WhenAll` inside `using` also put second `using` inside first.

Comment: You need the contexts until after the WhenAll because only then you know the contexts aren't needed anymore because the task is completed then. You created the task inside the using but you didn't executed it inside it or completely inside it (you didn't await it).

Comment: Does your code even compile? `Where` returns `IEnumerable<T>` not  `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`.

Comment: @Ralf Ah, of course. Feel very silly now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code will not compile at all because the `Where` method has an `IQueryable` output and not a `Task` type.
Assuming that we correct your code. Your problem goes back to the when you use Curly braces for scope, and practically, since your code is executed outside of those scopes, `DbContext` is no longer available.

Beginning with C# 8.0, the using keyword can be used as an attribute in the variable declarations of disposable objects ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/using)). The semantics is as you would expect -- the objects are auto-disposed at the end of the scope.

The following code is modified from your code and the best practice is to use `Using` Statement

```cs
await using MyContext ctx1 = new();
await using MyContext ctx2 = new();

var someData = ctx1.MyClass.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToListAsync();

var someOtherData = ctx2.MyOtherClass.Where(x => x.ID == id).ToListAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(someData, someOtherData);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the same instance, the problem is different.
`using` keyword with `IDisposable` objects defines the scope, after which object is disposed. So in your code:

```
using (MyContext ctx1 = new())
{
    someData = ctx1.MyClass.Where(x => x.ID == id); // defines the task
} 
// ctx1 is disposed here

using (MyContext ctx2 = new())
{
    someOtherData = ctx2.MyOtherClass.Where(x => x.ID == id); // defines the task
} 
// ctx2 is disposed here

await Task.WhenAll(someData, someOtherData); // actual tasks run, which happens after disposal of both contexts
```

So the solution is keep scope until you actually done with contexts:

```
using (MyContext ctx1 = new())
using (MyContext ctx2 = new())
{
    someData = ctx1.MyClass.Where(x => x.ID == id);
    someOtherData = ctx2.MyOtherClass.Where(x => x.ID == id);

    await Task.WhenAll(someData, someOtherData);

    //Do stuff with someData.Result, someOtherData.Result
}
```

Also be careful with `IEnumerable` and disposing, because the actual query (or several queries) execution could happen not when you've got `IEnumerable`, but when you enumerate it. It could also lead to the mentioned problem. If results are not large, I suggest using '.ToArray()' or '.ToList()' to force queries to be executed.